# EOFException when trying to use Anko verticalLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

Following a [tutorial](https://www.androidly.net/381/android-anko-layouts), I imported the Anko libaries by adding in my build.gradle in the app module:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:0.10.5"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.10.5"
```

I try the example:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import org.jetbrains.anko.*

class StartActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        verticalLayout {
            editText {
                hint = "Enter your name"
            }
            button("ECHO"){
                setOnClickListener {
                    toast("Button clicked")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For someone reason `import org.jetbrains.anko.* gets great out and AndroidStudio shows an error for verticalLayout by underlying it red. When I hover over it I get the error:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.builtins.BuiltInsBinaryVersion$Companion.readFrom(BuiltInsBinaryVersion.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MetadataPackageFragment.readProto(MetadataPackageFragmentProvider.kt:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MetadataPackageFragment.computeMemberScope(MetadataPackageFragmentProvider.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MetadataPackageFragment.access$computeMemberScope(MetadataPackageFragmentProvider.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MetadataPackageFragment$memberScope$1.invoke(MetadataPackageFragmentProvider.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MetadataPackageFragment$memberScope$1.invoke(MetadataPackageFragmentProvider.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:402)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MetadataPackageFragment.getMemberScope(MetadataPackageFragmentProvider.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.impl.LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl$memberScope$1.invoke(LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.impl.LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl$memberScope$1.invoke(LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:402)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.LazyScopeAdapter.getWorkerScope(LazyScopeAdapter.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.AbstractScopeAdapter.getContributedClassifier(AbstractScopeAdapter.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.FindClassInModuleKt.fin...
```

What do I have to do, so that this error isn't thrown anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your imports to the following :

```
import org.jetbrains.anko.button
import org.jetbrains.anko.editText
import org.jetbrains.anko.toast
import org.jetbrains.anko.verticalLayout
```

this works fine for me: [image]

and it also compiles and runs: (cutting out some of the toolbar as it has a project name in it)

[image]

here's a list of my dependencies, this is a brand new project from scratch so everything is default :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:0.10.5"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.10.5"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

even changing it to what you posted, works for me as well:

[image]

Might be related to either your version of kotlin or maybe an android studio bug, try updating your IDE, for this default project I'm using

```
Gradle: 3.4.0
Kotlin: 1.3.31
```

and this version of android studio (hope this helps):

```
Android Studio 3.4
Build #AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501, built on April 10, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6
```

---

Side note: I realized OP has no `setContentView` so I figured I had to try that as well, however:

[image]
[image]